# Avoid VSCode refactor format for svelte render conditionals

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, vscode-extensions, svelte

I have the following code:

```
{#if variable_A > 750}
        CODE HERE
{:else}
    {#if variable_B == false}
        CODE HERE
    {:else}
        MORE CODE HERE
    {/if}
{/if}
```

When pressing save, the code is automatically refactored and formatted by the [Svelte for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode) extension to:

```
{#if variable_A > 750}
        CODE HERE
{:else if variable_B == false}
        CODE HERE
{:else}
        MORE CODE HERE
{/if}
```

The result is technically correct, but I still prefer the first version.
Is there a way to disable this type of refactor, without disabling the auto format entirely?

Comment: You're using the [Svelte for VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode) to do the formatting, right?

Comment: Yes, disabling this extension doesn't auto format anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{#if variable_A > 750}
            CODE HERE
 {:else}
        {#if variable_B == false}
            CODE HERE
        {:else}
            MORE CODE HERE
        {/if}
 {/if}
```

It formats to

```
    {#if variable_A > 750}
            CODE HERE
    {:else if variable_B == false}
            CODE HERE
    {:else}
            MORE CODE HERE
    {/if}
```

But add some code above the if then it does not

```
    {#if variable_A > 750}
            CODE HERE
    {:else}
        Some code here also then it will not format like above and stay as it is
        {#if variable_B == false}
            CODE HERE
        {:else}
            MORE CODE HERE
        {/if}
    {/if}
```

This way you can keep the code which does not combine the if else

Comment: Thank you very much!